# How to know where the current line is at runtime in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to tell the Visual Studio 2010 debugger to show me where it is at?

That is, if I have a very long program and the program is somewhere in a loop, how can I know where it's at?

Comment: If you don't want to break, why not strategically place a `Console.WriteLine()` at spots you're interested in watching output from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't mean "in real time" - your program will be executing very fast...

To find where your program is, halt it via the debugger (in Visual Studio, menu Debug/Break All). The IDE will then show you the current line being executed.